# Communications between multiple Activities in a serial manner & returning the result to first Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `Activity` "A" which contains

1. List of addresses and contact details,
2. `Button`.

`Button` click navigates you to `Activity` "B" where you can enter address .When you submit the address, it will navigate you to another `Activity` "C" where you can enter contact details and verify them. Once the verification is done user will return to `Activity` "A" and the new address+contact details will be added to the already existing list.

How can I achive this ??

I already tried this one we can achieve this using multiple way..

We can use `startActivityforResult()` in multiple level like Pass C result to B and once the result received in B we can send the whole result back to A.

or we can pass the result from B to C and then `Broadcast` the total result to A from C.

Among these two which one is appropriate ?? Is there any better way to achieve this ??

Comment: @mehtankush earlier I didn't mentioned the solution i tried. now if you can suggest some better solution, it will be help full...

Comment: @GyanaranjanBiswal You didn't get the point. It doesn't work so, you need to try something first.

Comment: @GyanaranjanBiswal And yes, you need to broadcast it, with Intent (it's maybe first article with android programming). As you may know, Android system, using Intent for different calls inside and outside application. And you can implement it for your problem.

Comment: However, we already have other patterns for trasferring events. Like `Event Bus`.

Comment: I'd probably use `startActivityForResult()`, but what you're asking is basically for a recommendation, or opinions, which aren't really the best fit for Stack Overflow. If both are a possibility, do the one that's easiest for you.